# How can I use Semver with a NPM dependency targeting a private repository?

Tags: javascript, git, npm, dependencies, semantic-versioning

I try to import in my project a private repository as a dependency. The import itself works perfectly but I struggle with the Semver.

Right now, I do it as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "project-b": "git+ssh://git@github.com:projectowner/projectb.git#v1.3.1",
```

While it works as intended, I would like to update the version automatically while remaining in the same MAJOR patch, so `^1.x`.

I checked the documentation and had more hope with this:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "project-b": "git+ssh://git@github.com:projectowner/projectb.git#semver:^1.0",
```

But again, no luck.

Is what I try to achieve even possible with a private repository?

[EDIT]
Replaced `semver=` by `semver:`. Thank you [ferenc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10623884/ferenc)

[EDIT 2]
More info on the scenario I expect:

I first install the private repository as a dependency

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
    ...
    "projectb": "git+ssh://git@github.com/projectowner/projectb.git#semver:^1.0",
    ...
```

Then

```
npm install
```

The following is added to my `package-lock.json`

```
// package-lock.json

"projectb": {
    "version": "git+ssh://git@github.com/projectowner/projectb.git#27e31740bbff00c434832d4db5cc9ab99086d85d",
    "from": "git+ssh://git@github.com/projectowner/projectb.git#semver:^1.0",
    ...
```

Which is correct. The dependency is working and I can use its features/components in my current project. The commit hash is linked to the latest commit (release tag `1.7.0`)

I then deploy a new release in the project-b: `1.8.0`.

Back on my project-a, I expect to update the project-b dependency from `1.7.0` to `1.8.0` by running:

```
npm update projectb
```

However, nothing happens. I gain again the prompt and nothing has been printed in the terminal.

Comment: Make sure your npm is up to date. Also, try replacing the `:` in `github.com:projectowner` forward slash - I remember npm had a bug with parsing dependency urls with a colon in them.

Edit: Doesn't semver use `:` in the documentation? I.e `git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/cli#semver:^5.0`

Comment: I updated NPM, but no differences. The same thing for the slash and you are right, semver uses a `:`, which fix the `error: pathspec 'semver=^1.3' did not match any file(s) known to git` but doesn't update the version. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Do you have read access to the private repository? Please read [ask]. What exactly does "no luck" mean?  Did you get an error messages?  A different result than you expected?

Comment: Yes, I do have read access, and get no error messages. I expected the dependency to be updated to its latest version, the post is now edited with more information.